# How to check PRD (provider number/code) on smartphone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, imei

How do I pull up the PRD (provider number) either physically or through code (e.g.: for IMEI = *#06#, )

I looked under my phone but there's only SKU xxxx-xxxx and the IMEI

Alcatel 4060O 
Cricket

Comment: Android phones have a PRD number? Pretty sure that is just for Blackberry OS devices. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Unlock my phone's IMEI (it's locked to one provider cricket, but they want me to get a plan for 6 months to maybe let me loose)

Comment: Then you need to either buy an unlock code on eBay or from some other online seller (off topic here) and they only need your model and IMEI or serial number... keep the device for 6 months with active service,  or call Cricket and complain, if you have a valid reason like you no longer live in the country or something, you MIGHT get an unlock code. Unlocking devices is not what it used to be, the devices are locked deep within and that information generally isn't accessible or usable by users, and messing with it often bricks the device by design.

Comment: Also, I just looked... That is the Alcatel Streak, lots of places have the unlock code offered for ~$25, which ironically seems to be more than the cost of the phone (Cricket has it for free with a transfer or $10 with a new number) but is still significantly less than purchasing a new unlocked, retail device.